# Error in for loop

Tags: r

```
k<-21;

for(i in 5:k)
{
pharma[,i][pharma[,i]=="#N/A"]<- NA
pharma[,i][pharma[,i]=="NM"]<- NA
num<-sum(is.na(pharma[,i]))
n=1-num/length(pharma[,i])

if(n<0.8) {
rm(pharma[,i])
Else n=0
}
}
```

Basically trying to replace columns with NA and removing those where there are too many NA.

Comment: Can you expand the question to explain where the error is arising?

Comment: Read this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: downvoting due to neglect ... will upvote if improved.

Comment: Folks, sorry was busy at work. But nailed the error. below are the codes: for(i in c(5:18)){
    pharma[,i][pharma[,i]== "#N/A"]<- NA
    pharma[,i][pharma[,i]== "NM"]<- NA
    num<-sum(is.na(pharma[,i]))
    n<-1-num/length(pharma[,i])
    if(n >0.95) pharma1<-merge(m,pharma[,c(1,4,i)],all=TRUE)
    m<-pharma1
  }

Answer (score 2):

You did not tell us the error the code creates. But several observations:

- R is case sensitive. `Else` is not the same as `else` and `Else` is not correct
- You do not close the `if` statement before the `else`.
- There is no need to loop over the columns explicitly

Comment: Thanks Paul, found a way through, below is the new code:                for(i in c(5:18)){
  pharma[,i][pharma[,i]== "#N/A"]<- NA
  pharma[,i][pharma[,i]== "NM"]<- NA
  num<-sum(is.na(pharma[,i]))
  n<-1-num/length(pharma[,i])
  if(n >0.95) pharma1<-merge(m,pharma[,c(1,4,i)],all=TRUE)
  m<-pharma1
  }

Comment: If this answers your question, I would add it as a separate answer, describe what you did to fix the situation, post the code, and accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want *something* like

```
## extract the columns to manipulate
pp <- pharma[,5:21]
## set relevant values to NA
pp <- lapply(pp,function(x) x[x %in% c("#N/A","NM")] <- NA)
## estimate fraction NA and test
badcols <- colMeans(is.na(pp))>0.2
## remove bad columns
pp <- pp[,!badcols]
## put the manipulated stuff back together with the original structure
pharma <- cbind(pharma[,1:4],pp)
```

but it's hard to tell exactly without a reproducible example.